# What's the opposite of JavaScript's Math.pow?

Tags: javascript, math, algebra, polynomial-math

I'm having a mental block here, and algebra not really being my thing, can you tell me how to re-write the JavaScript code below to derive the variable, `c`, in terms of `a` and `b`?:

```
a = Math.pow(b, c);
c = ?
```

Thanks!

Comment: Slightly related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309084/what-is-the-reverse-of-x-powy-5

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
c = Math.log(a)/Math.log(b)
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that JavaScript is horrible at Math when dealing with precise numbers.

var c = 3;
var b = 10;
var a = Math.pow(b,c)

var d = Math.log(a)/Math.log(b);

// d should equal 3
// d actually equals 2.9999999999999996

Comment: @tbh__ is it safe to assume that if I'm working with integers and use Math.round() on the result it'll be accurate?  Specifically I know my value is a power of 2, so `let power = Math.round( Math.log(value) / Math.log(2) );` should be accurate in my case?

Comment: Ahh, it appears for my specific case Math has me covered with Math.log2(num)!

Comment: how do you obtain b if you have a & c?

Answer (score 9):

Logarithms.  You want the logarithm of a.  B is the base, c is the exponent, so

log<sub>b</sub> a = c

Comment: Seems true, but this is not JavaScript, only pure math.