# What is the reverse of x = pow(y, 5)

Tags: objective-c, math

I must have a mental block, but I simply can't find the reverse of this math function:

x = pow(y, 5);

I have x and 5, how do I find y ?

Here is a snip of my current code:

```
+(float) linearVolumeToVolumeCurve:(float)volume
{
    return pow(volume, 5);
}

+(float) volumeCurveToLinearVolume:(float)volume
{
    return ???
}
```

Comment: I guess it called root of nth power.

Comment: Nope, it would be a logarithm if the base were 5 and the exponent were the y.

Comment: I knew I could count on you all here on StackOverflow!
Thank you all for all the answers!

Comment: @H2CO3 nope, it'd be logarithm if it was `x = pow(5,y)`, realized that after spending 20 minutes writing an answer about logarithm definition  :)

Comment: Haven't I said that? pow(5, y) means 5 is the base, y is the exponent. see my 1st comment.

Comment: @H2CO3, but the question is NOT to invert pow(5,Y), but pow(y,5). So your comment is not at all relevant to the question at hand. You might as well have told us that Mr Green did it, in the library, with the lead pipe, but again, it would not be relevant.

Comment: Slightly related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016213/whats-the-opposite-of-javascripts-math-pow

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this (pseudo-code): `y = pow (x, 1.0 / 5);`

Comment: wrong, 1/5 will evaluate to 0 because it's integer division (no matter the 'pow' function takes a double).

Comment: @H2CO3 I've mention that it's pseudo-code -- I don't know Objective C. Though, have to admin it's pretty obvious thing for any C-derived language.

Answer (score 8):

You have to find the 5th root of y, which is the 1/5th power:

```
return pow(volume, 1.0/5);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
Y=Math.Log(x) / Math.Log(5)
```

Comment: This does not work for me. But Math.Pow(x,0.333333333333333D) does work to get a reverse of a power of 3.

Answer (score 1):

E.g.:

```
5 = pow(y, 5);
```

=>

```
   double y = pow(5, (1.0 / 5.0));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this.

if x=y^5

then y =x^1/5 means y=x^0.2

```
+(float) volumeCurveToLinearVolume:(float)volume
{
    return powf(volume, 0.2);
}
```