# How to get x of 2^x=8000?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the opposite of JavaScript's Math.pow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016213/whats-the-opposite-of-javascripts-math-pow)

```
2^x=i
```

Given i, how can we calculate x using Javascript?

Comment: i is the value which user will input from form.

Answer (score 7):

You want to take the logarithm of 8000. JS has the `Math.log` function which uses base `e`, you want base `2` so you can write `Math.log(8000) / Math.log(2)` to get the logarithm of 8000 base 2, which is equal to x.

Comment: Thanks Shad, I do not know the javascripts.

Answer (score 0):

You need the logarithm from the Math object. It does not provide a base 2 log so do the conversion:

```
var x = Math.log(8000) / Math.log(2);
```

[Reference to the javascript Math object.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_math.asp)

In the more general case we calculate 2^x = i this way:

```
var i; // Some number
var x = Math.log(i) / Math.log(2);
```