# Exponential decrease

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am stuck getting an exponential decrease from 100 to 0.
This is what I managed to get:

```js
var time_data = [];
var value_data = [];
var left = 100;
var  i = 1;

while (i <= 30) 
{
 left = left-Math.pow(i,i);
 
 if(left < 0)
 {
  left = 0;

 }
 
 value_data.push(left);
 time_data.push(i);
 
 i+=1;
}

var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
var data = {
    labels: time_data,
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
            borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            borderCapStyle: 'butt',
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointBorderWidth: 1,
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
            pointRadius: 5,
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            data: value_data,
        }
    ]
};

var option = {
 showLines: true
};
var myLineChart = Chart.Line(canvas,{
 data:data,
  options:option
});

function adddata(){
 myLineChart.data.datasets[0].data[7] = 50;
  myLineChart.data.labels[7] = "test add";
  myLineChart.update();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="250"></canvas>
```

```
while (i <= 30) 
{
    left = left-Math.pow(i,i);

    if(left < 0)
    {
        left = 0;

    }
```

And this is what I need to get

[image]

The problem is that don't know how to get a reverse version of `Math.pow`.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016213/whats-the-opposite-of-javascripts-math-pow

Comment: The reverse operation of exponentiation is the logarithm.

Comment: `f = (x) => (1/2) ** x`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the opposite of JavaScript's Math.pow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016213/whats-the-opposite-of-javascripts-math-pow)

Answer (score 3):

According to the graph, what you want is to start at (0,10) and then divide `y` by 2 every time `x` is incremented by 1.

Try this:

```
var time_data = [];
var value_data = [];

for (let i=0;i<=10;++i) {
    time_data.push(i);
    value_data.push(10/Math.pow(2,i));
}
```

This can be mathematically written as a decreasing exponential: `10 * 2^(-x)` or if you prefer `10 * exp(-ln(2) * x)`

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for exponential decay, do you need to use `Math.pow()`?  What's wrong with something like

```
left = left*factor
```

Where `0 < factor < 1`?

Looking at some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) for `Math.pow()`, the two arguments are base and exponent.  In your example, `left - 30^30` doesn't make much sense because it will result in a vastly negative number and then default to 0.

An expression using `Math.pow()` that will give the `i`th term of an exponential decay sequence is

`start_value * Math.pow(factor, i)`

Where again, `0 < factor < 1`.  The reduction in the value that you start with is compounded exponentially over each iteration.